# UIView not containing full width when using accessoryView in tableView swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using accessoryview for radio boxes and I want bottom of the text and accessoryView full width underline but its not working well not containing full width please check the screenshot and code.
In cellForRowAt method I'm using this code

```
let image =  UIImage(named: "radioUnselected")
let checkmark  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
checkmark.image = image
cell.selectionStyle = .none
cell.accessoryView = checkmark
```

[image]

Comment: Accessories are positioned next to the cell's content view. You probably want to add the image view as a subview of the cell instead, with your own constraints and stuff.

Comment: the accessory view has its own frame so rather than using accessory view you can add simple custom radio button on the right